How do I save the PNG image of a barcode generated from a Guid?
I'm working on an API that, in a specific step, will generate a barcode from a Guid and save said barcode as a PNG image to my local machine. I'm using the barcodelib library to try and accomplish this.
However, whenever I run the code below, it doesn't throw any errors, but it saves nothing to the specific file location.
[HttpPost("RegisterItem")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> RegisterItem()
{
   Guid itemId = Guid.NewGuid();
   Barcode itemIdBarcode = new Barcode(itemId.ToString(), BarcodeStandard.Type.Code128);
   itemIdBarcode.SaveImage(@"C:\Users\myName\Pictures\test.png", SaveTypes.Png);
}

After some testing I noticed itemIdBarcode.EncodedImage is coming as null, so I tried to call this setup instead:
[HttpPost("RegisterItem")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> RegisterItem()
{
   Guid itemId = Guid.NewGuid();
   Barcode itemIdBarcode = new Barcode();
   itemIdBarcode.Encode(BarcodeStandard.Type.Code128, itemId.ToString());
   itemIdBarcode.SaveImage(@"C:\Users\myName\Pictures\test.png", SaveTypes.Png);
}

However, the code doesn't advance beyond the itemIdBarcode.Encode() call. Any ideas how to get this to work?

First, ensure you have the correct version of the BarcodeLib package installed and referenced. If the package is outdated or incompatible, consider updating it via NuGet.
Here is your updated code below:
[HttpPost("RegisterItem")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterItem()
{
    try
    {
        Guid itemId = Guid.NewGuid();
        string itemIdString = itemId.ToString("N"); // It ensures that the GUID string is 32 characters without dashes, which may be easier for barcode scanners.

        // Create a Barcode object and encode the guid
        BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
        barcode.IncludeLabel = true; // This one is optional: includes the barcode value as a label

        var barcodeImage = barcode.Encode(
            BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128,
            itemIdString,
            System.Drawing.Color.Black,
            System.Drawing.Color.White,
        // Ensure that Width and Height parameters match your requirements
            300, // Width
            150  // Height
        );

        // Save the barcode image as a PNG
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\myName\Pictures\test.png";
        barcodeImage.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        return Ok(new { Message = "Barcode generated successfully", Path = filePath });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new { Error = ex.Message });
    }
}


The most up to date version of BarcodeLib changed the namespace from BarcodeLib to BarcodeStandard, so declaring the Barcode now looks something like:
BarcodeStandard.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeStandard.Barcode();
The Encode function now takes SKColors.Black and SKColors.White and the resulting barcodeImage object is of type SKImage, which Save() doesn't seem to be a method of. So I guess my next question is: How does one save an SKImage?

Probably because SkiaSharp rightfully doesn't want to bother itself with saving things to disk; it might even be used on systems that don't have disks. Perhaps something like using SKData encodedData = yourSKIimage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);         File.WriteAllBytes("output.png", encodedData.ToArray());

I got it working, here's what I did
`Barcode itemIdBarcode = new Barcode();
string itemString = itemId.ToString();
itemIdBarcode.IncludeLabel = true;
itemIdBarcode.Encode(
BarcodeStandard.Type.Code128,
itemString,
SKColors.Black,
SKColors.White,
600,
150);
itemIdBarcode.SaveImage(@"C:\Users\alexh\OneDrive\Pictures" + itemString + ".png", SaveTypes.Png);`
The issue was the Guid was creating too big a barcode and I hadn't specified the size
